# How do I exactly add ssh to PATH on windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, configuration

When trying to connect to Github on a new (I'm the first to try) Windows work computer, I'm getting this error:

> permission denied (Public Key)

Following instructions on Github, I then tried

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

This told me that

> ssh is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Googling that, I found out that this message means "ssh is not in the PATH".

Trying to add it to my path, I found

```
Variable name: Path
Variable value: :\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
```

What *exactly* do I enter to add ssh to the path. I'm not sure if it's

```
:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared\ssh.exe
```

or something else...

Comment: This question is better suited for superuser.com IMO

Comment: Er, I very much doubt that ssh is part of Windows Live! You probably should download putty to get an ssh client. Perhaps your work IT would be more appropriate people to ask.

Comment: When you find the ssh.exe file (for me it was in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"), Follow @Robert answer and be sure to leave no spaces between the semicolon and   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\" (entered without quotes).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to locate the directory that *ssh.exe* is in.

You then need to go into System Properties (hit WINDOWS KEY+PAUSE), go to Advanced system settings, click Environment Variables...

Scroll down in the scrolling window at the bottom, until you see "Path" under "Variable".  Click it, click Edit...

Go to the end of the value, add a semi-colon if one isn't there already, and type the path to the directory that *ssh.exe* is in.

Comment: thanks, I found a folder .ssh but inside I don't see 'ssh.exe' rather there's only "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub" and "known_hosts". I assume that wouldn't be it?

Comment: Are you using CYGWIN?

If you are it's under C:\CYGWIN\bin

Comment: on the command line [WINDOWS KEY+R enter "cmd"], type dir ssh.exe /s to find the directory

Comment: I'm not using CYGWIN (can't see it on this computer) @Jannie it said "file not found"

Comment: @JannieT before typing `dir ssh.exe /s` should `cd /` be typed?  I needed to do this to back out to `C:` on my windows machine and then the `dir` command you suggested found my `ssh.exe`.

Comment: I use cygwin but I still had to install ssh onto cygwin. Note that the location cygwin puts ssh is under the cygwin user directory, not your Windows user directory.

Comment: OpenSSH is now available on Windows 10. Once you've installed it, it'll be located in C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH. OpenSSH installation instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Answer (score 20):

SSH.exe will  be in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

Comment: This is true, however after I appended this to the windows `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` the `cmd` still complains `'ssh' is not recognized as ...`

Answer (score 0):

If Git for windows is installed,`Bash` shell is installed with `ssh` and others.

You can run ssh  from within Bash:

From the Command Prompt run the command:

```
bash -c "ssh -vT git@github.com"
```

Bash shell is aware of the path of ssh.

No need to add path of ssh in path environment.

Answer (score -6):

Here is the answer:

Install the `PUTTY` and go to: `C:\Program Files\PuTTY`, copy the icon "putty" and paste to 
`C:\WINNT\system32`. Done.

Click> `start` > `Run` > `PUTTY` & hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: `PuTTy` and `open ssh` are simmular but not the same